# LoadLibrary failure with rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2, loadlibrary

After upgrading R and rpy2 I found a LoadLibrary failure problem with rpy2 when importing the R package stats. After running the following code:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.objects.packages import importr
rstats = importr('stats')
```

I receive the error message

```
RRuntimeError: Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module cannot be found.
```

Other modules are imported correctly, unless they import stats themselves. I have tried to reinstall R and rpy2 to no avail. A [similar issue](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/201743623-LoadLibrary-failure-after-upgrade) reported a problem with a path in the .Renviron file. This file does not exist in my computer.

My R_HOME is C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3 and my R_USER is C:\Users\user.name.

Could you help me find what is the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Is the "*C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll*" present on your computer? Also, what does the following command: `python -c "import sys;print(sys.version)"` output?

Comment: @CristiFati Yes, I forgot to mention it, the stats.dlI is present in my computer. The output of the command is: `2.7.13 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 19 2016, 13:29:36) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]`

Comment: Hmm, I don't have *R*, but you should check that *.dll* dependencies (http://www.dependencywalker.com), and see if some are missing.

Comment: @CristiFati Thanks. Dependency Walker cannot find R.dll, Rblas.dll nor Rlapack.dll. However, all of them are in C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin\x64 and I have no problems when running R alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin\x64 to the path. I think that this address was deleted from the path when I uninstalled the previous R version. And you need to install the address manually to the path after installing the new version, according to the [R for Windows FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#Rcmd-is-not-found-in-my-PATH_0021).

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me ... I was using the 32-bit version which is at: C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin\i386.

Comment: I still cannot solve the problem because I am using Mac.

Answer (score 0):

For those with anaconda, I solved the problem using `conda install rpy2`

Also added the entry `C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2\bin\x64` to my user `Path` variable.

And added the variable `R_HOME` with value `C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2`

And added the variable `R_USER` with value `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\rpy2`

I tried many different suggestions, but this was the only solution.